# postgresql jsonb nested foreign reference

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I have a table for Master_Vendors which has foreign key for vendor type.

```html
e.g Master_vendor (Vendor_type e.g. Car, Hotel)
      |
      |_____CAR
      |      |
      |      |_____Car_model_Id(F.K.)
      |      |
      |      |_____Car_make_Id(F.K.)
      |      |
      |      |_____Car_owner(F.K.)
      |                 |
      |                 |___Employee_Id(F.K.)
      |                         |
      |                         |____Department_Id(F.K.)
      |______Hotel
             |
             |...so on (hotel type of vendor will have it's own details)
```

I have these many foreign keys to be handled. How can make the jsonb structure in such a way that I can get data from foreign key. 
    I don't want to make whole structure of foreign table against each foreign keys.Just want to create the reference which will get me the data from foreign master table.